# SQL - Adding a total line for each distinct value in column 1

Tags: sql, db2

I am trying to add a "total count" line for each distinct value coming from my first column. I tired to make a UNION ALL but made a total mess of things. (based on the TL.OP_CODE value.)
Any help GREATLY appreciated. Sorry for my formatting...

```
select 
tl.op_code as "OPS Code",  tl.current_status AS "Status", tl.service_level as "Service",
tl.Bill_number as "Bill number", tl.trace_no as "Trace No", 
tl.pick_up_by  AS "PU By", tl.origname, tl.origcity, tl.origprov,
tl.deliver_by AS "DEL By", tl.destname, tl.destcity, tl.destprov, tl.pallets 
from tlorder tl
where tl.current_Status NOT IN ('CANCL')
order by tl.op_code, tl.currency_code, tl.pick_up_by
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Sorry about that - I am using a DB2 database - hope that makes sense

Comment: Are you going to have some additional column for this count in the result set, which will be NULL for every base row?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following approach:

```
WITH MYTAB (op_code, A, B) AS
(
-- You may put your original SELECT here 
-- instead of this artificial VALUES
VALUES
  (1, 1, 1)
, (1, 1, 2)
, (2, 1, 1)
) 
SELECT op_code, A, B, CAST (NULL AS INT) AS CNT
FROM MYTAB T
  UNION ALL
SELECT op_code, NULL, NULL, COUNT (1) CNT  
FROM MYTAB
GROUP BY op_code
ORDER BY op_code, CNT DESC;
```

| OP_CODE | A | B | CNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |  |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |  |
| 1 |  |  | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |  |
| 2 |  |  | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

Use Rollup for example if I have student_score table and I am trying to get sum of scores for distinct scores here.

```
| student_id | score |
| ---------- | ----- |
| 1          | 95    |
| 2          | 95    |
| 3          | 95    |
| 4          | 93    | 
| 5          | 93    |
| 6          | 98    |
| 7          | 98    |
| 8          | 99    |
| 9          | 91    |
| 10         | 91    |
 

SELECT student_id, sum(score) as score from student_score GROUP BY ROLLUP(score, student_id) ORDER BY score;

| student_id | score |
| ---------- | ----- |
| NULL       | 948   |
| 9          | 91    |
| 10         | 91    |
| NULL       | 182   |  
| 4          | 93    |
| 5          | 93    |
| NULL       | 186   |
| 1          | 95    |
| 2          | 95    |
| 3          | 95    |
| NULL       | 285   |
| 6          | 98    |
| 7          | 98    |
| NULL       | 196   |  
| 8          | 99    |
| NULL       | 99    |
```